# How to remove extra big space under the footer? I can see it in IE9 & Firefox9 but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm fighting with this nasty problem. I've developed a page template for my website (using wordpress software & some plugins) but after doing all hard work now I'm experiencing a big space under the footer in two of the browsers I'm using. Internet Explorer 9 & Mozilla Firefox 9. It is fine in Google Chrome. Here is the [link of the page](http://worldocricket.com/?page_id=8183).

Can someone come up with its solution? Thanks.

Comment: step one for any HTML issue validate: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fworldocricket.com%2F%3Fpage_id%3D8183

Comment: I tried it before but majority of these errors don't exist.

Comment: every one exists, the validator is correct.

Comment: try using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Comment: @Dagon: Well, I'm not using strict Doctype, but still it is saying that attribute "property" can't be used, you must be using "Strict". But I'm "Transitional" Doc, which should be fine. But I'll try to solve them.

Comment: @ruslyrossi - Thanks for the link. I used it and also inspected my html with Mozilla (Web Developer mode), both are not telling anything about the extra-space under the footer.

Comment: validator is clear "Errors found while checking this document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!"

Comment: hrmmm..maybe u should check line by line because maybe u forget to put clear:both..

Comment: @ruslyrossi - Your advice worked for me. After digging the code hard, I found that my wordpress tab (with almost 42 sub-pages) was interfering and I just changed it from 'published' to 'pending review'. And now my page is space-free in all 3 browsers. Thanks to you and all others who tried to help me. May GOD bless you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks** to [ruslyrossi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/946283/ruslyrossi) and all others who tried to help me. After digging the code hard, *I found that one of the tabs (pages) {having almost 42 sub-pages} was interfering*. I just turned its status from 'Published' to 'Pending Review' & it worked. Now I've no extra-space under the footer in IE9 or MF9. I got what I was looking for.

My question received (-3), may be it was unclear or a stupid question. But yes, it was my exact question.

Comment: The problem is sometimes difficult to explain to all, but we still try to help anyone no matter what the question.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked source of the web page in IE at the end of the html code it showing like

........

```
 <div id="footer" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px;">
    <a href="http://worldocricket.com" title="World Of Cricket">World Of Cricket</a>       &copy; 2011 - For the brilliance of Cricket
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Please correct this code. mentioned the html code in single body tag

Answer (score 0):

Your page has 96 Errors, 1 warning(s) in W3C HTML Validator. Solve all of them problem should be solved.

You have more then one `</html>` and `</body>`